# Error: Invalid hook call React native using navigator

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error invalid hook call. Here is the code I am using https://blog.waldo.io/react-native-side-menu-guide/

My react-dom version:
react-native-sidemenu@ /home/ornela/Work/react-native-sidemenu/react-native-sidemenu
├── react-dom@16.13.1
└─┬ react-native-web@0.13.18
└── react-dom@16.13.1 deduped

And my react-native version:
react-native-sidemenu@ /home/ornela/Work/react-native-sidemenu/react-native-sidemenu
├─┬ expo@42.0.3
│ └─┬ react-native-safe-area-context@3.2.0
│   └── react-native@0.63.2 deduped
└─┬ react-native@0.63.2
└─┬ @react-native-community/cli@4.14.0
└── react-native@0.63.2 deduped

Here is the code:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator 
        drawerType="front"
        initialRouteName="Profile"
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
          itemStyle: { marginVertical: 10 },
        }}
   
      >
    {
      DrawerItems.map(drawer=><Drawer.Screen 
        key={drawer.name}
      />)
    }
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

);
}

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In which component you are getting the error ?

Comment: NavigationContainerInner
/home/ornela/Work/react-native-sidemenu/react-native-sidemenu/NavigationContainer.tsx:70
  67 |   validatePathConfig(linking.config);
  68 | }
  69 | 
> 70 | const refContainer =
     | ^  71 |   React.useRef<NavigationContainerRef<ParamListBase>>(null);
  72 | 
  73 | useBackButton(refContainer);

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your code .